# What is the inverse Laplace transform of some form of gamma function?

Tags: laplace-transform, gamma-function, inverse-laplace

Let $$F(s)=\frac{\Gamma(1+b)\Gamma(1+s)}{s(\Gamma(1+b+s)-\Gamma(1+b)\Gamma(1+s))}$$

What is the inverse Laplace transform of this function?

**$b$ are positive real numbers. Even if this could be solved for $b$ an integer, it will be helpful.**

Or if it cannot be done directly, can we do it approximately?

Many thanks!

Comment: Might I ask for the context where this function came about?

Comment: Coming from a continuous time random walk(CTRW) model for subdiffusion behavior. this function is the trapping time probability density function in Laplace space. So I want to reverse it back to the t space.

Comment: Thanks. A difference of gamma functions in the denominator is quite a tricky thing, you might want to try to approximate a solution numerically.

Comment: You are right. I saw someone asked similar questions (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957247/inverse-laplace-of-gamma-function), is there any possibility could use these result to figure out my question?

Comment: If you are working with a and b that make it easy to identify poles of your function then I suppose you could modify that approach. But for arbitrary $a,\,b>0$ this may be difficult.

Comment: Mathematica can't do it. I only have two comments: 1. The $\Gamma(1+b)$ in the numerator comes out. 2. The $s$ in the denominator comes out as the time integral of the rest of the inverse transform.

Comment: For $b$ positive integer then $\Gamma(b+1+s) =\prod_{m=0}^{b-1} (s+1+m) \Gamma(1+s)$ so the denominator is $P(s) \Gamma(1+s)$ where $ P(s) = s (\prod_{m=0}^{b-1} (s+1+m)-\Gamma(b+1))$ is a polynomial and hence you are asking about the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\Gamma(1+b)}{P(s)}$ which is found from the factorization of $P(s)$ and either the residue theorem or the partial fraction decomposition.